# How to get the relist history for a given item id?

Tags: ebay-api

That is. When a listing has ended, but it was relisted (and hence, a new item id exists), you get the message...

> This listing has ended. The seller has **relisted this item** or one like this.

...at the top of the page, with a link to the new listing.

So, starting from the original listing, one could get the whole chain of item id's just by following those links.

My question is, *is there a way to programmatically get this history of relists?* If not the full history, a way to get the ancestor/parent or descendant/child listing for a given item would be enough.

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to use the Item.ListingDetails.RelistedItemID property of the parent item that has ended. See http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getitem.html#Response.Item.ListingDetails.RelistedItemID for details and https://ebay-sdk.intradesys.com/s/d9d4f495e875a2e075a1a4a6e1b9770f for an example.

HTH, --Andreas

Comment: So **Item.ListingDetails.RelistedItemID** gives me the child.

And **Item.RelistParentID** gives me the parent.

Is that right? I wonder why I didn't see them at first!

Thanks.